# Making a loading page out of <Section> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am fairly new to using html and css beyond the minor basics. I am trying to make a loading page for a website and can't seem to find an example for my exact case.

Here is the html I want to show only on loading:

```
<section id="hero">
      <div id="mast">
          <h1><img src="data:image/image/gif;base64/=" alt="bus" /></h1>
          <h2>Let's Travel</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow"><a data-scroll data-speed="750" data-easing="easeInOutCubic" data-url="false" href="#navigation"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></div>
</section>
```

I saw an example on stackoverflow loading class of html like this:

```
  <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $(".classname").fadeOut("slow");
        })
    </script>
```

Is there away to have a section load by the id instead of just a css class?

Comment: `$('#hero').fadeOut("slow");`...? You can use the `$('#hero')` selector and then call whatever function you want. Sorry, it's a little unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can use CSS style selectors. So, if I want to select all elements from a class I can do `$('.classname')`, if I want to select an element by id: `$('#idname')`, if I want to select all `<p>` tags, I could do `$('p')`. Hell, I could select all `<bold>` tags within `<p>` tags by doing `$('p > bold')`.

Anyway, I'd take a look at how CSS selectors work, and then you'll now how to select anything in jQuery: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

In your case, I'm guessing you want to use `$('#hero').fadeOut()`